# Set return data from Flowable not working in Android

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have these methods:

```
    fun getMyObjectByCode(code: String): Flowable<Array<MyObject>> {
        return interfaceRest.getObject(code)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

and then call like this:

```
   fun getMyObjectByCode(Code: String): MyObject {
        var resultMyObject = MyObject()

        compositeDisposable.add(
            viewmodel.getMyObjectByCode(code).subscribe { result ->
                // just need the first element
                Log.i(TAG, "result :${result[0].toString()}")
                resultMyObject = result[0]
            }
        )

        return resultMyObject
    }
```

and finally:

```
var myobject = getMyObjectByCode(code)
```

It is working fine since I can see the correct MyObject in the Log, but the return object is never set with the value, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `viewmodel.getMyObjectByCode(code)`  doesnt emit a value and before that the return statement is called thats why you are gettting such results. you cant return object from this function it ll always get delayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As disposable requires and observable(Single Flowavble etc).You can try with

```
 Single.just(viewmodel.getMyObjectByCode(code))
```